# Multi-line tooltips in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

I'm trying to display tooltips in Java which may or may not be paragraph-length.  How can I word-wrap long tooltips?

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: Don't tool tips automatically word-wrap if they're wrapped in HTML tags?  I'm not sure, so I'm not putting this in as an answer.

Comment: Paul: Only if you have explicit line-breaks.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

If you wrap the tooltip in `<html>` and `</html>` tags, you can break lines with `<br>` tags.  See https://web.archive.org/web/20060625031340/http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=10653 for examples and discussion.  Main take-awy from that discussion: `fButton.setToolTipText("<html><font face=\"sansserif\" color=\"green\">first line<br>second line</font></html>");`

Or you can use the JMultiLineToolTip class that can be found many places on the net, including
https://github.com/ls-cwi/yoshiko-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/yoshiko/internal/view/JMultiLineToolTip.java

Comment: I used the JMultiLineToolTip class you suggested.  Once I used setFixedWidth() to limit the tooltip to a reasonable size, it worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: the first link seems to be no longer working.  it has redirected me to a movie webpage

Comment: @KevinCrum replaced with a link to the wayback machine. It was 12 years ago, after all.

Answer (score 24):

Tooltip text which starts with "`<html>`" will be treated as HTML. Of course that might be very wide HTML.

You can override [JComponent.createTooltip](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#createToolTip()) to replace the tooltip with your own component which can display whatevee you like.

Answer (score 24):

I know this one is quite old but i found a quite simple solution using HTML code!

Just use a HTML Paragraph with a fixed width:

```
setToolTipText("<html><p width=\"500\">" +value+"</p></html>");
```

Comment: What if I want to display text that is much shorter than tooltip size? "max-width" tag doesn't work here

Comment: You can even skip the closing tags. Maybe it's not a valid html, but it works fine.

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```
jTextField1.setToolTipText("<html>"
                              + "Line One"
                              +"<br>"
                              + "Line 2"
                         + "</html>");
```

Comment: This does not answer the asker's question. He was asking about wrapping when it is displayed, not in source code.

Comment: @ArtB this example code does give a two-line tooltip as asked.

Comment: @ja4  This example code help me to make multi-line tooltips, very easy way

Comment: @Sled Actually, it does answer the question, whether unintentionally or not. All tooltip texts in Java which are wrapped in the <html> tag are line broken automatically. So if "Line 1"  would be really long for example, it would multi-line itself, making "Line 2" the third or fourth line.

Answer (score 5):

Use HTML tooltips and manually break your lines (a simple word tokenizer with a fixed line length should do it). Just make sure your tooltip text starts with "<HTML>". Break lines with "<BR/>" or "<P>". I realize it's not the most clean solution and Java's HTML support is horrible, but it should get things done.

Answer (score 4):

This could be improved somewhat, but my approach was a helper function called before setting tooltip that split the tooltip text at provided length, but adjusted to break words on space where possible.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 */
public class MultiLineTooltips
{
    private static int DIALOG_TOOLTIP_MAX_SIZE = 75;
    private static final int SPACE_BUFFER = 10;

    public static String splitToolTip(String tip)
    {
        return splitToolTip(tip,DIALOG_TOOLTIP_MAX_SIZE);
    }
    public static String splitToolTip(String tip,int length)
    {
        if(tip.length()<=length + SPACE_BUFFER )
        {
            return tip;
        }

        List<String>  parts = new ArrayList<>();

        int maxLength = 0;
        String overLong = tip.substring(0, length + SPACE_BUFFER);
        int lastSpace = overLong.lastIndexOf(' ');
        if(lastSpace >= length)
        {
            parts.add(tip.substring(0,lastSpace));
            maxLength = lastSpace;
        }
        else
        {
            parts.add(tip.substring(0,length));
            maxLength = length;
        }

        while(maxLength < tip.length())
        {
            if(maxLength + length < tip.length())
            {
                parts.add(tip.substring(maxLength, maxLength + length));
                maxLength+=maxLength+length;
            }
            else
            {
                parts.add(tip.substring(maxLength));
                break;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");
        for(int i=0;i<parts.size() - 1;i++)
        {
            sb.append(parts.get(i)+"<br>");
        }
        sb.append(parts.get(parts.size() - 1));
        sb.append(("</html>"));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Use like

```
jComponent.setToolTipText(MultiLineTooltips.splitToolTip(TOOLTIP));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass JToolTip, which is a Component, and override createToolTip() on the component.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version which I have used before, it works well if you are loading your tool tips from ResourceBundles:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JToolTip;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.ToolTipUI;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * A tooltip that wraps multi-line text.
 */
public final class MultiLineToolTipUI extends ToolTipUI {

    private static final int INSET = 2;

    private static final Pattern LINE_SPLITTER = Pattern.compile("$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

    private static final MultiLineToolTipUI SHARED_INSTANCE = new MultiLineToolTipUI();

    /**
     * Install the multi-line tooltip into the UI manager.
     */
    public static void installUI() {
        String toolTipUI = MultiLineToolTipUI.class.getName();
        UIManager.put("ToolTipUI", toolTipUI);
        UIManager.put(toolTipUI, MultiLineToolTipUI.class);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
    public static ComponentUI createUI(JComponent c) {
        return SHARED_INSTANCE;
    }

    private MultiLineToolTipUI() {}

    @Override
    public Dimension getMaximumSize(JComponent c) {
        return getPreferredSize(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(JComponent c) {
        return getPreferredSize(c);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(JComponent c) {
        String[] lines = LINE_SPLITTER.split(((JToolTip) c).getTipText());
        if (lines.length == 0) {
            return new Dimension(2 * INSET, 2 * INSET);
        }
        FontMetrics metrics = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont());
        Graphics g = c.getGraphics();
        int w = 0;
        for (String line : lines) {
            w = Math.max(w, (int) metrics.getStringBounds(line, g).getWidth());
        }
        int h = lines.length * metrics.getHeight();
        return new Dimension(w + 2 * INSET, h + 2 * INSET);
    }

    @Override
    public void installUI(JComponent c) {
        LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(c, "ToolTip.background", "ToolTip.foreground", "ToolTip.font");
        LookAndFeel.installBorder(c, "ToolTip.border");
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        int w = c.getWidth(), h = c.getHeight();
        g.setColor(c.getBackground());
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        g.setColor(c.getForeground());
        g.drawRect(0, 0, w, h);
        String[] lines = LINE_SPLITTER.split(((JToolTip) c).getTipText());
        if (lines.length != 0) {
            FontMetrics metrics = c.getFontMetrics(c.getFont());
            int height = metrics.getHeight();
            int y = INSET + metrics.getAscent();
            for (String line : lines) {
                g.drawString(line, INSET, y);
                y += height;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void uninstallUI(JComponent c) {
        LookAndFeel.uninstallBorder(c);
    }

}
```

And you would use it by calling this method, before your UI is created:

```
MultiLineToolTipUI.installUI();
```

Then in your properties files just insert newlines to wrap your tool tips as desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you just add `<html>` to your tooltip text, it will appear to work until you have `/*...*/` or HTML in your text. Use `<html><pre>` or escape your text. I also had to use `<font size=3>` to get it looking somewhat decent.

Comment: It's important to mention escaping, good job :)

Answer (score 1):

I created a utility class that automatically formats strings to a specific length with `<br>` tags. It is based on the MultiLineToolTips class posted by Paul Taylor, but his has a bug in it that skips portions of the string and does not actually limit the string to a specific length.

To use my class, simply invoke the splitToolTip method by writing `MultiLineToolTips.splitToolTip(yourString);` or `MultiLineToolTips.splitToolTip(yourString, maxLength);` if you want to split it to a specific maximum length. This will create nicely formatted tool tip strings.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/** A helper class to split strings into a certain length,
 * formatted with html {@literal<br>} tags for multi-line tool tips.
 * Based on the MultiLineToolTips class posted by
 * <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/1480018/paul-taylor">Paul Taylor</a>
 * on <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/13503677/9567822">Stack Overflow</a>
 * @author <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/9567822/andrew-lemaitre?tab=profile">Andrew LeMaitre</a>
 */
public final class MultiLineToolTips {

    /** Private constructor for utility class. */
    private MultiLineToolTips() {
    }

    /** Default max length of the tool tip when split with {@link #splitToolTip(String)}. */
    private static final int DIALOG_TOOLTIP_MAX_SIZE = 75;

    /** A function that splits a string into sections of {@value #DIALOG_TOOLTIP_MAX_SIZE} characters or less.
     * If you want the lines to be shorter or longer call {@link #splitToolTip(String, int)}.
     * @param toolTip The tool tip string to be split
     * @return the tool tip string with HTML formatting to break it into sections of the correct length
     */
    public static String splitToolTip(final String toolTip) {
        return splitToolTip(toolTip, DIALOG_TOOLTIP_MAX_SIZE);
    }

    /**  An overloaded function that splits a tool tip string into sections of a specified length.
     * @param toolTip The tool tip string to be split
     * @param desiredLength The maximum length of the tool tip per line
     * @return The tool tip string with HTML formatting to break it into sections of the correct length
     */
    public static String splitToolTip(final String toolTip, final int desiredLength) {
        if (toolTip.length() <= desiredLength) {
            return toolTip;
        }

        List<String>  parts = new ArrayList<>();
        int stringPosition = 0;

        while (stringPosition < toolTip.length()) {
            if (stringPosition + desiredLength < toolTip.length()) {
                String tipSubstring = toolTip.substring(stringPosition, stringPosition + desiredLength);
                int lastSpace = tipSubstring.lastIndexOf(' ');
                if (lastSpace == -1 || lastSpace == 0) {
                    parts.add(toolTip.substring(stringPosition, stringPosition + desiredLength));
                    stringPosition += desiredLength;
                } else {
                    parts.add(toolTip.substring(stringPosition, stringPosition + lastSpace));
                    stringPosition += lastSpace;
                }
            } else {
                parts.add(toolTip.substring(stringPosition));
                break;
            }
        }

        StringBuilder  sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size() - 1; i++) {
            sb.append(parts.get(i) + "<br>");
        }
        sb.append(parts.get(parts.size() - 1));
        sb.append(("</html>"));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```