# How to use new line character within a ToolTip

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi-line tooltips in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868651/multi-line-tooltips-in-java)

It is very strange.  All I wish to do is make my tool tip multi-lined.  I have added the "\n" character to the string I am passing at appropriate places.  In fact, I print out that same string, and it does have the line breaks.  However, the tooltip does not.  Here is what I do:

```
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                String s = arg0.getItem().toString();
                for(InfoContainer i: mc.myInfo)
                    if(s.equals(i.getId())){
                        selector.setToolTipText(i.getInfo());
                        System.out.println(i.getInfo());
                        return;
                    }
            }
        }
```

However, the tooltip does NOT have the carriage returns, while the System printout DOES.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868651/multi-line-tooltips-in-java

Comment: [You can use basic HTML][1] to format your Tooltip-Text.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868651/multi-line-tooltips-in-java

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about using: `"<html>" + firstLine + "<br>" + secondLine + "</html>"`

Comment: Don't forget to escape the content of `firstLine` and `secondLine`. Imagine what would happen when they contain '<' or '>' for example.

Answer (score 6):

Use the HTML tag `<br/>`:

```
selector.setToolTipText("<html>" + i.getInfo() + "<br/>some text next line</html>" );
```