# Make all tooltips multiline in Java (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, tooltip

Tooltips in my application can be quite long, therefore I'd like them to have line breaks.

**I don't want to use html** as I'd prefer to set a (max) width of my tooltips instead and have the line breaks dynamically.

In the accepted answer the this similar question [Multi-line tooltips in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868651/multi-line-tooltips-in-java) I read about `JMultiLineToolTip`. Unfortunately the provided link doesn't work anymore and there are many different `JMultiLineToolTip` out there. Therefore my two questions:

1. Which `JMultiLineToolTip` is a good one to use?
2. How can I use such a class to represent **all** of the tooltips in my application?

**EDIT:** as everyone seems to recommend the use of html, is there a way to define the width of my tooltip in pixels (or some other unit than number of characters) using html?

Answer (score 7):

If you are not afraid of extending swing tool tip, you can create your own JMultiLineToolTip:

1. Extend JTooltip In the extended Tool tip component implementation,
2. set a custom tool tip UI In customUI implementation
3. Implement`paint()` method to write given string in multi line

[Here is an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/MultiLineToolTipExample.htm) - it shows how to use it as well

However, to answer your questions:

1. Which JMultiLineToolTip is a good one to use?

   Use `<html>`
2. How can I use such a class to represent all of the tooltips in my application?

   Per compopnent, it is easy but tedious to achieve as you will have to override [creatreToolTip()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#createToolTip%28%29) API. But if you want to change it globally, you may:

   (i)Simple way - Register your custom tooltip UI with the `UIManager` at the beginning of your execution.

   `UIManager.put( "ToolTipUI", "SeNormToolTipUI" );`

   `UIManager.put( "SeNormToolTipUI",Class.forName( multiLineToolTipUIClassName ) );`

   (ii) complex way

   You will have to start implementing your own look and feel. In the look and feel implementation, you would provide defaults for `ToolTipUI` as your UI implementation and then set that look and feel to the application you are running. For instance take a look at the [MetalLookAndFeel implementation](http://www.koders.com/java/fid555169BAAFFA92F84223B548C83D4655041815E3.aspx?s=204#L884). You may just extend that part and implement your on lnf.

So, it is better to use `<html>`

Comment: I did not mean complex=difficult. I mean rather it is un-necessary.

Answer (score 4):

1) `Html` is easiest of ways for plain `JToolTip`

2) use `JWindow`(un_decorated `JDialog`) with `JTextArea`, better would be `JTextPane` (supporting stylled text),

- the disadvantage is you have to manually set window to the `Point`, you have to manually set for `setInitialDelay` and `setDismissDelay` (Swing Timer), `setVisible(true/false)`
- the advantage is that you using full manageable top level container with definitions for own parent

3) I use `JLabel` with `Html` formatted and stylled text added to the `GlassPane`, notice easiest alternative is use non_opaque `JLayeredPane` (Java6) or `JLayer` (Java7)