# JFreeChart customize BoxAndWhiskerToolTip

Tags: tooltip, jfreechart, boxplot

I am adding tooltip to Box and Whisker plot.

```
final BoxAndWhiskerRenderer renderer = new BoxAndWhiskerRenderer();
String tooltipformat = "Max: {5}\nQ3: {7}\nQ1: {6}\nMin: {4}\nMean: {2}\nMedian: {3}";
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new BoxAndWhiskerToolTipGenerator(tooltipformat,NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));
```

I get the result below.

[image]

Instead of getting the tooltip label in a column, I got it in a row. Why does the **\n** is useless?

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML will do.

```
String tooltipformat = "<html><body>Max: {5}<br>Q3: {7}<br>Median: {3}<br>Q1: {6}<br>Min: {4}<br>Mean: {2}</body></html>";
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new BoxAndWhiskerToolTipGenerator(tooltipformat,NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) uses a `ToolTipManager.sharedInstance()`, you can break multi-line tooltips as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45872701/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/868651/230513). As another example, the following changes to [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), seen [here](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html), produce the results illustrated below.

```
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator(
    "<html>Series: {0}<br>Category: {1}<br>Value: {2}</html>",
    NumberFormat.getInstance()));
```

[image]