# JavaFX TableView multiline tooltip with cell factory and bindings

Tags: javafx, tableview, tooltip, bind, factory

I have using this code snippet to create tooltips for every tableView cell I propagate via cell factories:

```
    private <T> void addFileTooltipToCells(TableColumn<FileTableBean,T> column) {
Callback<TableColumn<FileTableBean, T>, TableCell<FileTableBean,T>> existingCellFactory  = column.getCellFactory();
    column.setCellFactory(c -> {
        TableCell<FileTableBean, T> cell = existingCellFactory.call(c);
        Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        tooltip.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty().asString());
        tooltip.setShowDuration(Duration.seconds(30)); 
        tooltip.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 12");
        cell.setTooltip(tooltip);
        return cell;
    });
}
```

Problem is that the tooltips can sometimes have lots of data and should be multilined. From here I found that one should simply wrap the tooltips with  and possibly set 
 where necessary. However, the above carefully somewhere copied and trial-error tested code snippet doesn't like the idea. I have tried:

```
tooltip.textProperty().bind("<html>"+cell.itemProperty().asString()+"</html>");
tooltip.setText("<html>"+cell.itemProperty().asString()+"</html>");
```

First says in IDE: Incompatible String cannot be converted to ObservableValue
Second one generater following tooltips: " String binding [invalid] " :)

And before somebody starts with the usual "the error message says it all, read it" stuff, I know that there are probably a simple answer for this, but having these lambdas combined with the binding concept and cellfactories, I just have to give up and try to get some guidance from here.

Comment: See if ControlsFx PopOver is a better node to use here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: How about [`wrapText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html#wrapTextProperty) + `prefWidth`? How should the `html` part fix anything? If you really want to display a string containing those substrings, use `Bindings.concat("<html>", cell.itemProperty(), "</html>")` should be used to create a `ObservableValue<String>` instead of a `String` which is not allowed as parameter of `bind`.

Comment: Thanks @fabian, I missed the wrapText part when reading the tooltip docs. The html idea came from several topics like this: [link|(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868651/multi-line-tooltips-in-java) 
Moreover I'm little bit disappointed to which level StackOverflow has gone lately. You need to be really careful not asking a "stupid question" or you're downvoted to oblivion or spammed with the same "please provide minimal blablabla". The code snippet above was enough to Fabian to give me good answer. No need to spam hundreds of lines of code when the question is really related on few

Comment: Just to note, the question you linked to relates to Swing where HTML content is supported in things like tooltips. JavaFX's controls (e.g. `Tooltip`, `Label`, `TextArea`, etc.) do not support HTML (at least, their default skins don't). That's why the HTML tags weren't working.

Comment: Thanks @Slaw. Thought that as some kind of successor for Swing, JavaFX would have herited this html support, but I'll stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to those who face the same problem. You can use the "normal" binding but just apply the tooltip preferences to every tooltip the cellfactory creates simply by defining:

```
tooltip.setMaxWidth(750);
tooltip.setWrapText(true);
```

Setting preferable width will create tooltips with lots of extra blanks if the data is shorter than the width. Max width works like a charm. Next step is probably to make width parameter dynamic so that it calculates the max width based on stage resolution.